# Some additional characters appended after the URL

Tags: php, session, url, tracking, privacy

My client website created using php code.

However, when I click on any link on any web page, the url bar append some characters as below "VzFqJRV95E4". It is different from another computer and different browsers showing different characters.

I copy the website to my localhost also display different characters.

> http://localhost/newbridge/Frequently-Asked-Questions.php#.VzFqJRV95E4

[Screenshot from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWm8i.png)

How can I remove the codes? I think it is session tracking. It's so annoying and I think I should remove it to protect user privacy.

Comment: you need to change this in your php code. i assume you're redirect is appending the annoying codes.

Comment: Could you show some code you think could be associated with this problem? There isn't much background into what the program is and therefore it is hard to help. You mentioned $_SESSION, so start there. I'm interested, as I've never seen this.

Comment: have look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37467/strange-characters-after-url-uafabbty-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [rocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4719765/rocky)!
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37467/strange-characters-after-url-uafabbty-ie

The URL is actually generated by AddThis plugin's Address Bar Sharing Analytics.

Info can refer to this URL http://www.addthis.com/academy/what-is-address-bar-sharing-analytics/

> How it Works
>
> Address bar share tracking works by appending a special tag to your URL once your page has loaded. Your URLs will start to look like this:
>
> http://example.com/blog#AHb4gs1hwck
>
> In this case, “#AHb4gs1hwck” is a semi-random value which identifies each page view. When a user clicks on an URL like this we’ll know that they were the recipient of an address bar share and we’ll count a share and a click for your site. This tag contains the time that the page was viewed by the sharer so we can properly attribute the share. If that recipient subsequently shares your page to someone else, we’ll be able to measure it separately as a “reshare”, taking into account the various generations of your viral sharing.
>
> Note: these types of tags (called URL fragments) will not affect your SEO because they are discarded by search engines during web crawling.